# Check if function is called inside a try clause

Tags: python, attributes, getter-setter, try-except

I'm writing an API and  I have used some managed attributes because they are retrieved from network, therefore it may generate errors.

Inside the getter-setter I want to check if API user have used a try clause around the attribute get/set.

```
def getter_or_setter():
    try:
        network_operations()
    except:
        if called_inside_try():
            raise
        else:
            log.error('error string')
```

Comment: So your API only raises when the caller is "prepared" to handle it? That's bad API design.

Comment: I don't think that would be good design. However, see [Python: inspect where an exception raise would go](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4298108/222914)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing: I don't have an answer to your question, and have no idea if it's actually possible to determine if your function is called from a try block :)

That being said, what I'm sure of however, is that it is a weird thing to do. You should leave the decision to raise an exception or fail silently to the caller based either on an **explicit** parameter or an alternative way of calling your function.

As an example, I believe you should consider how `dict` handles missing keys:

- When using `d['missing']`, the dict raises a `KeyError`
- The caller can choose to use `d.get('missing')` to avoid an exception.